# Fast in-place partitioning of sorted array into two sorted subarrays

Tags: c#, algorithm

*Edit - I removed all unnecessary context explanation - too wordy and ultimately irrelevant to the problem.  In summary I'm partitioning arrays of coordinates during the process of building a balanced KD Tree ([see wikipedia article, Construction section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Construction) for more.  I actually have k parallel arrays of n items that each have to be partitioned by the same comparison)*

This is not homework - I've written the question like it is to ensure that all the nuances are communicated.

Given the sorted arrays:

```
 int[] ints =  { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
 //this one is important - my current solution fails on this
 int[] ints2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

***Note due to a clarification asked by a colleague, all that's guaranteed about these arrays is that `element[n]` will be less than or equal to `element[n+1]`.***

Successful operations on these will separate them into two sub arrays `L` and `R` (indicated below):

```
/*ints == */  { 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 6 }
              /*|> L <|  |>   R  <|*/

/*ints2 == */ { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 }
              /*|>    L    <|  |>    R    <|*/
```

`L` contains the integers that are odd and `R` contains those that are even, whilst retaining the original sort-order of those elements within those subarrays.

The function will ideally **NOT** resort to re-sorting the elements (a lengthy sort operation will already have been performed in advance) and it won't use a temporary array.  I believe that means I'm looking for O(N) complexity and O(1) memory.

The function can be provided with the start and end elements of each sub array - i.e. the caller can know in advance how many items will fall on the left/right sides (possibly by scanning the array in advance for odd/even).  ***Edit*** in reality it starts off just as an array; so a solution that can work *without* these values is good, because otherwise the complete solution can only ever be at best O(2n) complexity in reality if an initial pass is required.

This where my current attempt is at now - I've updated it and commented it from what was in the original post.

```
public void DivideSubArray(int[] array, int leftStart, int leftCount, 
  int rightStart, int rightCount)
{
  int currentLeft = leftStart, currentRight = rightStart;
  int leftCounter = leftCount;
  int temp;
  int readahead;
  while (leftCounter != 0) {
    if ((array[currentLeft] % 2) == 0)
    {
      //remember the element we swap out
      temp = array[currentRight];
      //Set as next item on the right. We know this is the next lowest-sorted 
      //right-hand item because we are iterating through an already-sorted array
      array[currentRight++] = array[currentLeft];
      // * read ahead to see if there are any further elements to be placed
      // * on the left - move them back one by one till there are no more.
      readahead = currentLeft + 1;
      while ((array[readahead] % 2) != 0)
      {
        array[currentLeft++] = array[readahead++];
        leftCounter--;
      }
      //Now write the swapped-out item in, but don't increment our currentLeft.  
      //The next loop will check if the item is in the correct place.
      array[currentLeft] = temp;
    }
    else //this item is already in the correct place
    {
      currentLeft++;
      leftCounter--;
    }
  }
}
```

When called as follows:

```
int numOdd = ints.Count(i => (i % 2) == 1);
DivideSubArray(ints, 0, numOdd, numOdd, ints.Length - numOdd);
```

It produces the expected array for `ints` (and many other arrays), but not `ints2`:

```
{ 1, 5, 3, 7, 9, 0, 2, 6, 4, 8 }
```

So it partitions correctly - but swaps `3,5` and `6,4`.  I understand ***why***: because in the first loop `5` is swapped to the left, then `2` is propagated over because the algorithm says that `5` is odd and should stay.  I have a decision tree written out that'll fix it, but having followed it a few loops it infers that the solution is recursive.

I'm struggling to see how to get around this without running more sort operations within the sub array or creating temporary lists/arrays as workspace.  Of course, though, a sort might increase complexity but keep the memory requirement; and if it turns out to be the fastest solution then it would make sense to use it.

You can see my current fastest (in run-time) and best memory solution under my answer.  As a yardstick - the above attempt not only produces an incorrect result, but it also takes 3 times as long as the code in my answer.

I *feel* there must be a simple way to exploit a single 'spare' variable to swap the items - I just can't see it - I'm hoping the SO collective brain will :)

Of course, if the answer is 'no' then so be it.

Comment: The idea is to do it in O(N) right? Just asking as a O(N*log(N)) solution is obvious

Comment: @izomorphius yeah O(N) is the goal - I've managed to get a solution for `ints` but it then leaves `5` at the end of the array

Comment: @izomorphius - Sorry my previous comment didn't make a lot of sense at the end - `5` was left at the `ints2` array.  Anyway... I've done it and posted the solution as an answer; reading ahead along the left-hand side before committing that swap was the answer.

Comment: @izomorphius I spoke too soon - as soon as I give it an even-numbered array it breaks... back to the drawing board.

Comment: really take a look at my response. I believe it may make your life easier :)

Comment: I have updated my answer with code on how to do what I propose. Hope now it is more clear.

Comment: Just a (probably obvious) note: the problem would be easy if the sorted elements were on a linked list instead of an array. Do you have to use an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a solution together that did not use a temporary array - it was incredibly slow for large N; I'm not even going to post the code for it, it was that bad!

**Edit - This is improved upon my original solution.  Complexity is technically O(2n) (because the List.CopyTo method uses Array.Copy which is O(n) according to the framework documentation) and memory is O(n).**

Yes, the solution simply takes the array and does the split on the fly, rather than relying on knowledge of odd/even split in advance.  This means (when regressed back to my actual code) that an initial pass is not required - so it's preferable.

This solution is trivial: it scans through the array, moving odds back to the start of the array (or leaving them where they are if they are in the correct place already) and adds evens to a list.  When the loop is complete, the list is copied to the remainder of the array.  It satisfies my complexity requirement at the expense of memory - at worst O(n) - and is a big improvement on the code I was already using anyway (it was two times faster than a two-list solution).  It also doesn't require an initial pass to get the odd/even split.

```
public void DivideSubArray(int[] array)
{       
    int currentOdd=0;
    List<int> even = new List<int>(array.Length / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((array[i] % 2) != 0)
        {
            even.Add(array[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentOdd != i)
                array[currentOdd++] = array[i];
            else
                currentOdd++;
        }
    }
    even.CopyTo(array, currentOdd);
}
```

Note the initial capacity of the list - as Mooing Duck mentions in comments below, I might be able to improve further by exploiting some probabilities and choosing a slightly higher value (assuming that on average a roughly even split will be observed).

That said, the algorithm performs slowest with an even split - if there are more odd items, then it's just a bunch of swaps.  If there are more evens then, yes, more `Add` operations are required, but it'll only be a List resize that'll kill performance.

My last attempt is going to be to see if I can achieve what izomorphius suggested - build odds in the correct order and evens in reverse or any order without an extra array.  If that's possible then that solution will be O(1) memory but O(n + (complexity of sort)) - and if it's performance, in practise, is even half the speed as the above solution I might go for it.

Comment: Resize each one to `Length*9/16` or something, which is _slightly_ over 50%, so that (as long as you have more than ~16 elements) usually neither will need to resize. (use a power of 2 as the denominator)

Comment: That is a good idea, and one I think I will use. in practise its possible that the actual data I'm working with could all be destined for one side or the other (its actually a set of points lying above or below a splitting plane for a kdtree balanced insertion) but I can see that this will over, in general a better chance of avoiding a resize in most cases.  Thanks!

Comment: Andras: as you say it's always possible they'll be uneven, but statistically, (assuming 50/50 chance) the more elements you have, the closer it should be to a perfect 50/50 split.

Comment: By my math if you have ~100 elements, 9/16s will mean you only have to resize 26% of the time.  For ~200 elements, resize only 10% of the time.  For ~1000 elements, resize about 0.00334% of the time.

Comment: yeah, and i will be dealing with at least 200k elements :)  I'll take those odds!

Comment: Andreas, didn't you say in your question that you know the size of the two subarrays in advance?

Comment: I did, mainly because a quick scan will have been done to figure out the counts.  I did manage another version which calculated the split as it went along, but bubbling up the right hand elements turned out to make it exponentially complex.  I'll go for either-one that just takes the array and one which is told the split.

Comment: @coffee_machine I'm learning this problem as I go along.  I thought I would have the split in advance without scanning, but then I realised that the only way thats possible is if I conduct an O(N) scan first (id misunderstood my data).  So really I just have an array and I need to split it.  However, I will still take a solution that can do what I originally ask, if its O(1) memory.  The solution I've posted above is just the fastest I've found.

Comment: You can spare one array and simply use the existing array to copy the evens or ods in the order they do appear. That does at least cut down the costs to half of the memory currently needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make your task easier in the following manner: First modify the array in a way that first the odd numbers are written in the beginning of the array in ascending order and then the even are written in decreasing order in the end. For your example {0,1,...6} this would look like {1,3,5,6,4,2,0}. After you do that, do another linear pass to reverse the second part of the array(this is quite easy and straight-forward).

Why do I think this should be easier? Well because the thing you should in the first step is just what a regular qsort algorithm would do(with a bit stranger comparison operator). You can search the internet to see how the qsort partition is done(there is one example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095153/quicksort-not-sorting-correctly) for instance). I truly believe that if you split your problem on this two steps implementing the solution will be easier for you. Also note the overall complexity is not changed.

Hope this will help you.

EDIT: here is how I believe you could do the first part of my suggestion:

```
public void DivideSubArray(int[] array, int leftStart, 
              int leftCount, int rightStart, int rightCount)
{
    int currentRight = rightStart + rightCount - 1;

    int current = leftStart;
    while (current < currentRight) {
        if ((array[current] % 2) == 0)
        {
            int temp = array[current];
            array[current] = array[currentRight];
            array[currentRight] = temp;
            currentRight--;
        } else {
            current++;
        }
    } 
}
```

I am not providing the code to reverse the even part as I believe it is pretty straight forward and I also wanted to stress on the fact how much this approach simplifies the code.

Comment: unfortunately this first pass reorders `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` to `9,1,7,3,5,6,4,8,2,0`

Comment: ahh... sure I did a mistake for the odd numbers. Will fix that shortly

Comment: @AndrasZoltan now that I gave it a thought I think the problem is way more complicated then I initially thought. I was thinking about can't you integrate this within your sort algorithm? Simply define the comparison operator in a bit more complicated way?

Comment: Problem is that the sort is done once, then smaller sub arrays are split recursively based on a comparison to a different value each time (the mod here is actually a comparison of all values against a single coordinate in one of k dimensions). If you like, imagine that the nature of odd and even in my simplified problem is actually different each time, so there's no way to combine the two.  You're right it is complicated, but I do think your initial hunch is correct, and might be achievable without advanced knowledge of the location of the split.  I'm going to have a play :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any 'direct' way to partition the list without one end or the other getting scrambled, but one can still have a linear-time constant-space solution.  The partitioning approach offered by izomorphius will result in the right side of the ending up in reverse order (easily correctable in linear time), and the other end being scrambled in somewhat predictable fashion, with those elements that came from the right side being intermixed, in reverse order, with those that came from the left.  One can easily in constant time identify whether a given element came from the right side (just compare it with the last item in the left side), and can then thus easily in linear time reverse the sequence of the elements that have been moved from the right side to the left side.

Once one has done that, one is left with a partitioning problem which is very much like the original, but only half the size; the only difference is that the splitting criterion is based upon whether value of a node is greater or less than the "original" last element, rather than whether it is even or odd.  One can thus apply essentially the original algorithm on a smaller set of data.  Since one can determine in advance which side of the split is going to have more items, one can place the split so that the remaining side will be no more than half the size of the original.  The net effect is that partitioning an array of size 2N takes O(1) times as long as partitioning an array of size N.  Since a single-element array can be done in constant time (which it obviously can), this means that *partitioning an arbitrary-sized array which consists of two arbitrarily-intermixed runs of sorted data, into two disjoint runs of sorted data, can be done in linear time using constant space*.

Incidentally, while it won't matter for integers, it's important to note that the above algorithm relies upon the ability to compare two elements and know whether the first belongs to the left or right of the second.  It can thus not be used as the basis for a stable sort algorithm.

Comment: In fact my solution does not even order the even numbers correctly. After some thought I found out that my approach is not quite it. I am still struggling to figure out a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can I try myself on this thread. I can see you are speaking of C#. I don't know the language, but I don't think this is crucial for the task.

There is something missing in the problem description - where the sorted array is coming from. Probably I should have posted a comment asking for clarification, but I decided that I will go and write an answer covering all possibilities I can think of. Hopefully that way the answer will serve more people in the future.

Basically the task as is puts us in a box: "You have an array, now split it in place". However, I would like to reason a bit on the origin of this array:

- **Case 1:** The array is read from somewhere and sorted in the code (in-memory). If this is the case splitting the evens from the odds has an elegant solution, that does not put any overhead:

  1. Determine the number of odds and evens (by single pass through the array `O(n)`).
  2. Determine the largest and smallest number in the array. Lets call them `MAXM` and `MINM`. This can be done in the first pass to determine the even and odd number.
  3. Pass once more through the array adding `MAXM - MINM + 1` to every odd number. The goal is to make sure that all odd numbers become larger than the evens. This is linear in time `O(n)`
  4. Split the array using kth_element algorithm (basically a single pass of the quick-sort pivotal separation). Split the evens from the odd making use of the fact you already know how many are each and that all odds are larger than all evens. The algorithm runs in linear time `O(n)`, but regretfully I have reference only for [C++ library implementation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/) (no C#).
  5. Pass through all array slots corresponding to the odd numbers and subtract `MAXM - MINM + 1` from each number to get the original odd numbers. This is also linear in time `O(n)`
  6. Finally sort the portion of the evens and odds separately. This will not increase the complexity of the sorting overall, but you will have the to portions separated one from another.
- **Case 2:** You read the array already sorted from some persistent storage, say file on a hard disc and know in advance the number of odds and evens.

  1. In this case you just need to have to places in the array you input numbers: one is for the next to follow even number and one is for the next to follow odd number. This solution should be obvious and it does not impact the performance at all.
- **Case 3:** You read the array already sorted from some persistent storage, say file on a hard disc and but do NOT know in advance the number of odds and evens.

  1. Start filling the evens from the beginning of the array and the odds from the end of the array. That way, at the end the two sequences will meet in the middle.
  2. Thus you will have the evens split form the odds, but the odd numbers will be in decreasing order, instead of increasing. You just go and do inplace reverse of the odd part (which is also linear) and you have the desired array.

Hopefully at least one of the described scenarios will suite you and you will be able to solve your issue using the idea from it.

Comment: Hey Boris, thanks for your answer.  Yes, I took out the context here, because it made the question very long, you can see it in the edit history tho.  In short, I have k arrays of n elements representing the sort orders of coordinates in each one of the k dimensions, they are prepared in order to do a balanced insertion into a kd tree. At each level of insertion i have to split each array into a sub array representing coords that lie above or below another coordinate. So each subarray is partitioned many times over, in successively smaller chunks. I think there is wisdom in your third...

Comment: ...point.  if I can find a way to do one pass, and build one half of the array in the correct order, whilst building the other half in the reverse order that might just work.  I'm also really glad to be faced with a problem for which there's clearly no easy solution! I have C++ in my blood, too, so don't worry about that.  The second half of the 'Construction' topic on the KD tree page on Wikipedia describes the overall thing I'm trying to achieve here.  I have a working tree implementation, but I want a *killer* balanced insertion routine :)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: If C++ was an option I would suggest you try `std::stable_partition`. If there is __sufficient available memory__ its complexity is linear, otherwise the worst case is O(n log n). I don't think you're going to get both O(n) complexity _and_ O(1) memory.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, yeah Ive managed an O(2n) complexity and O(n) memory solution, it quite literally is twice as slow as my current two-list solution, but its possible that using half the memory will be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there might be an O(n) time and O(1) space algorithm. But it might be too complex for us to understand.

I will convince you this by:

1. show you a special case of the original problem, we call it A.
2. Consider the reverse of problem A, we call it problem B. And show that if we get a O(n) time and O(1) space solution for either of them, then we can modify it to solve another problem.
3. I will show you that problem B can be solved in O(n) time and O(1) space, but the solution is quite complicate and need a lot of math.

So this means, it's unlikely to get an easy solution to your problem, else we can solve problem B easily.

### 1.Consider a special case:

Let A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, from 1 to 2n and n = 4 in this example. So you want to change it to {1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8}, right? We call it problem A. In general it means you have an array A of size 2n, from A[1] to A[2n], you want to re-range it to A[1],A[3],A[5]...,A[2n-1],A[2],A[4],A[6],A[2n]. This is a special case of your problem. If you get a solution for your problem, then it will be easy to solve problem A.

### 2.The reverse of problem A.

Let's consider a related problem. Let B = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, and we want to change it to {1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8}. This is just like you have a deck of cards, and you want to do a perfect shuffle, which is split them into 2 equal parts and merge them alternatively. So in general, you have an array B of size 2n, from B[1] to B[2n]. You want to re-range it to B[1],B[n+1],B[2],B[n+2],....B[n],B[2n].

Then you will realize that problem A and problem B are reversed operations. That is, for an array of size 2n, if you do it with operation B, and then do it with operation A, then it will become the original array, and it will be the same if we do B first then A.

If you have some knowledge of permutation, you will know that if we get an algorithm for A, then we can change it to make it works for B. If you are not familiar with this, I can elaborate more later.

### 3.Problem B is not easy to solve.

Does it exist an O(n) time and O(1) space algorithm for problem B. It does, you can look it at [Computing the Cycles in the Perfect Shuffle Permutation](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~jellis/Publications/shuffle.ps). It's an 12 page paper which means you are unlikely to come up with this solution in interview. I have read it and it really need a lot of math in Number theory. And it's more a theoretical solution.

### Conclusion:

**It seems there isn't a simple(which means doesn't require a 10 pages paper) O(n) time O(1) space solution to your problem, even for the special case in Problem A.** Else we can modify it to solve problem B. I'm not sure whether there is a O(n) time O(1) space solution to your generalized problem.

If you are really interested in this problem. You can look at Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming. There is a chapter discuss In Situ Permutation.

It might not be easy to understand my idea, so if you have any question please comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
// stable_partition.cpp
// example general inplace stable partition.

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Fwd, typename Pred>
  Fwd
  inplace_stable_partition(Fwd first, Fwd last, Pred pred)
  {
    ptrdiff_t nmemb = std::distance(first, last);

    if (nmemb == 1)
      return pred(*first) ? last : first;
    if (nmemb != 0)
      {
        Fwd split = first;
        std::advance(split, nmemb/2);

        first = inplace_stable_partition(first, split, pred);
        last = inplace_stable_partition(split, last, pred);

        std::rotate(first, split, last);
        std::advance(first, std::distance(split, last));
      }
    return first;
  }

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  using namespace std;

  vector<int> iv;
  for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    iv.push_back(i);

  copy(iv.begin(), iv.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
  cout << endl;

  inplace_stable_partition(iv.begin(), iv.end(), bind2nd(modulus<int>(), 2));

  copy(iv.begin(), iv.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would have been better with some sort of explanation to let readers know why it is a potential answer to the question posted.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your are looking for a stable in-place sorting algorithm with a special relational order of elements (any odd number is smaller than any even number).

Given that, I think you cannot be better than O(n ln n).

I would go for an in-place merge sort.

If you don't need to preserve the order of the elements with the same value, go for a quick-sort, which is much simpler for in-place processing (however, with billions of elements, this may not be well suited).

Comment: spoke too soon - even-numbered arrays break it.

Comment: It's not limited by the sorting algorithm lower bound though, since it's already sorted.  It can be done in O(n)

Comment: Mooing, you are ignoring the O(1) space constraint set by Andreas. The algo to this is called in-place partitioning and I've never seen any O(n)-time implementation (which does not mean impossible). I think the only (efficient) way of doing this is to sort the array and thus I think the lower bound is O(n ln n).