# Quicksort not sorting right

Tags: c#

Sorry, i know there's been a bunch of questions on quicksort, but there's a bug in this which i cant find.

```
public static void QuickSort(int[] sort)
{
    QuickSort(sort, 0, sort.Length - 1);
}

private static void QuickSort(int[]sort, int first, int last)
{
    int i = first;
    int j = last;
    int pivot = (i + j)/2;
    int temp;

    while(i <= j)
    {
        while(sort[i] < sort[pivot]){i++;}
        while(sort[j] > sort[pivot]){j--;}

        if(i <= j)
        {
            temp = sort[i];
            sort[i] = sort[j];
            sort[j] = temp;             
            i++;
            j--; 
        }

    }

    if(first < j)QuickSort(sort, first, j);
    if(last > i)QuickSort(sort, i, last);
}
```

It seems fine but sorts this array

```
int[] sortMe = {2,5,6,4,8,9,6,3,21,2,5,4,8,9,6,5,46,6,3};
```

like this:

```
2,2,3,4,3,4,5,5,6,6,5,6,6,8,8,9,9,21,46
```

instead of the obvious right order.

Comment: Try sorting it on every permutation of very small arrays until you find one that doesn't work, then run it through the debugger and compare it to pseudocode/what it SHOULD do

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095153/quicksort-not-sorting-correctly

Comment: Unfortunately this question in current state is unlikely to be useful for SO visitors. If you want to write code yourself - do that, debug (better yet add basic tests) and get it working. Otherwise simply use existing sorting methods. You can improve your question by showing test cases you already verified (and added unit tests for).

Answer (score 2):

I think your `pivot` choice is wrong.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot

> In very early versions of quicksort, the leftmost element of the
>   partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately,
>   this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays, which is a
>   rather common use-case. The problem was easily solved by choosing
>   either a random index for the pivot, choosing the middle index of the
>   partition or (especially for longer partitions) **choosing the median of
>   the first**, middle and last element of the partition for the pivot.

Just change your  `int pivot = (i + j)/2;` to `int pivot = first;`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] sortMe = { 2, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 3, 21, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 6, 5, 46, 6, 3 };
        QuickSort(sortMe, 0, sortMe.Length - 1);

        foreach (var item in sortMe)
            Console.Write(item + " ");
    }

    private static void QuickSort(int[] sort, int first, int last)
    {
        int i = first;
        int j = last;
        int pivot = first;
        int temp;

        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (sort[i] < sort[pivot]) { i++; }
            while (sort[j] > sort[pivot]) { j--; }

            if (i <= j)
            {
                temp = sort[i];
                sort[i] = sort[j];
                sort[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }

        }

        if (first < j) QuickSort(sort, first, j);
        if (last > i) QuickSort(sort, i, last);
    }
```

Output will be;

```
2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 8 8 9 9 21 46
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/ireNoQ).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calculating `pivot` as `index` and then comparing it with the `sort` array value, Whereas you are modifying your `sort` array inside the outermost `while` loop. `Pivot` should be the initial value for the outermost while loop pointing to `sort` array index, later you compare it with that value, not with the `sort` array based on index.

Your method should be:

```
public static void Quicksort(int[] sort, int first, int last)
{
    int i = first, j = last;
    int pivot = sort[(first + last) / 2]; //change here

    while (i <= j)
    {


        while (sort[i] < pivot) //Change here
        {
            i++;
        }

        while (sort[j] > pivot) //Change here
        {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j)
        {
            // Swap
            int tmp = sort[i];
            sort[i] = sort[j];
            sort[j] = tmp;

            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    // Recursive calls
    if (first < j)
    {
        Quicksort(sort, first, j);
    }

    if (i < last)
    {
        Quicksort(sort, i, last);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 just for the explanation of the real problem which I couldn't. :)

Comment: @SonerGönül, where is my +1 :P

Comment: Ups, since I'm at work now, my boss called me and I forgot your upvote `:D`